# Woocommerce custom image for cart thumbnail

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am modifying product image in product detail page using fabricjs(Canvas Image). Now I want to use that customized image as a cart thumbnail after clicking Add To Cart button.

I have already saved other custom data in cart item data using below code,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_fields_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );

function add_custom_fields_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){

if(isset($_POST['color']))
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['color'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['color']);

if(isset($_POST['desc']))
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['desc'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['desc']);

$cart_item_data['custom_data']['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
WC()->session->set( 'custom_data', $cart_item_data['custom_data'] );

return $cart_item_data;
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_custom_fields_as_order_item_meta', 20, 4);
function save_custom_fields_as_order_item_meta($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
if( ! isset($values['custom_data']) )
    return;

$text_domain ='woocommerce';

// Save values:

if( array_key_exists('color', $values['custom_data']) ){
    $item->update_meta_data( __('Colors', $text_domain), $values['custom_data']['color'] );
}

if( array_key_exists('desc', $values['custom_data'])){
    $item->update_meta_data( __('Description', $text_domain), $values['custom_data']['desc'] );
}
}
```

I have saved custom canvas image using AJAX into the media

```
function my_action_javascript() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('can');

        canvas.setHeight(300);
        canvas.setWidth(350);
        var img_src = $('#custom_image').attr('src');
        
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = img_src;
        img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";  // important - set crossOrigin before src!
        img.onload = function(){
             canvas.setBackgroundImage(new fabric.Image(img, {
                width: canvas.width,
              height: canvas.height,
                originX: 'left',
                originY: 'top'
              }), canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
        };
        canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() *1.0);
        $("#colorpicker").change(function(){
          var clr_pick = $(this).val();
          var text = new fabric.Textbox('Name',  
          { 
              width: 100,
              fill: clr_pick,
              cornerColor: 'black'
          }); 
          canvas.add(text).renderAll();
        });

        $( "#single_add_to_cart_button" ).click(function(e) {
       
          var photo = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');      
          var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>';          
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: ajaxurl,
              data: {'action': 'custom_product_design', 'photo': photo },
              success: function(response) {
                  
              }
        });
    });
});
</script> <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_product_design', 'custom_product_design' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_custom_product_design', 'custom_product_design' );

function custom_product_design() {

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_path = str_replace( '/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $upload_dir['path'] ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$image_parts = explode(";base64,",$_POST['photo']);
$decoded = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
$filename = 'wigo.png';
$hashed_filename = md5( $filename . microtime() ) . '_' . $filename;
$image_upload = file_put_contents( $upload_path . $hashed_filename, $decoded ); 
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');


// Without that I'm getting a debug error!?
$file             = array();
$file['error']    = '';
$file['tmp_name'] = $upload_path . $hashed_filename;
$file['name']     = $hashed_filename;
$file['type']     = 'image/png';
$file['size']     = filesize( $upload_path . $hashed_filename );
// upload file to server

// use $file instead of $image_upload
$file_return = wp_handle_sideload( $file, array( 'test_form' => false ) );
$filename = $file_return['file'];
$attachment = array(
 'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
 'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
 'post_content' => '',
 'post_status' => 'inherit',
 'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($filename)
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename );
/// generate thumbnails of newly uploaded image
$attachment_meta = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$attachment_meta);
die;
}
```

Now I am getting custom image from `atachment_id`, Now I just want to save this new image into `custom_data` of `$cart_item_data` into the ajax call and use it as a cart thumbnail using filter `woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail`.